# Run the dll file in c# using command prompt

Tags: c#-4.0

How to compile the .dll files created by c# through command prompt?

Comment: dlls are already compiled, what you want to do ?

Comment: execute the created project dll files through cmd

Comment: I successfully executed ...Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DLLs aren't executables, but class libraries. There is no entry point defined, therefore you can't "execute" them.

However, you can either change your output type to executable (.exe) or create another project (with output type set to executable), reference your .dll and call the entry method from the new project.

Comment: Actually I have a .dll for one project. how to execute that from command prompt.. please show some samples to achieve that..

Comment: A dll is a collection of classes. You can't execute it as it has no defined entry class / method (like, for example, `void main()` in class `Program`). What you can do is to write a little program which references the dll and calls some method within the library in it's own `main()` method.

Comment: Having referenced the .dll file, instantiate the class you want to use and call the appropriate method on the class instance (or call a static method on a class, if applicable).

Comment: I add the reference to that console application project......and, now the problem with including Header(using ...) is problem.....How to import that in "using" area

Comment: Use the object explorer to find the class you need, take the full qualified name and use it directly or add the full namespace of that class as using statement in the header.

Comment: Just use google and searh for "c# include dll". For example, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3707x96z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx.

Comment: If DLL files are not executable, what happens when we call a DLL file via `rundll` or `rundll32` in the form of `rundll[32] <dllname> ,<entryPoint> <OptionalRequirements>`? For example we install a printer using `rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n\\ComputerName\PrinterName`.or We can lock the screen using `rundll32 user32.dll,LockWorkStation` right? So what happens in this situations?

Comment: @TheGoodUser this way you call a method within a DLL file. The executable is `rundll` or `rundll32`. As you can see from the parameters, the entry point must be specified by the caller. A simplified explanation would be: `rundll[32]` loads the given library and executes the method specified at `<entryPoint>`, passing given parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Use `/target:library` to build a DLL:

```
csc /target:library Foo.cs
```

Or

```
csc /target:library /out:MyLibrary.dll Foo.cs
```

See the [docs for csc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to compile source code files into an assembly (DLL), call [csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the command line compiler for C#.